# GlassFish does not start

Tags: java, glassfish

I'm starting with the Glassfish technology. I found this impediment, after having downloaded and put on disk c: the installer, I go to the windows command screen and execute the command "asadmin start-domain", but my answer is

-jar: illegal argument.

I have already configured the JAVA_HOME and the route. But it does not work. Could you suggest something?

The version of the Glassfish Platform is 4.1.2

The Java Development Kit version is 8

[image]
Command line
asadmin start-domain

[image]
Path JAVA_HOME

Comment: provide a domain `asadmin start-domain domain-name`

Comment: asadmin start-domain domain1. domain1 is the default domain, but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ramanlfc's comment, you will also need to check your environment variables. On Windows, you will need to add your JDK's binaries location (%JAVA_HOME%) to the system path in order to start GlassFish:

https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-on-windows-10/

Comment: Yes, I have configured in the same way, but I still do not get

Comment: Have you tried inserting %JAVA_HOME% at the start of the path?